# MTW file to R object

Tags: r, minitab

How do I import Minitab files into R? especially a file with the extension mtw. But how can I convert a minitab dataset into an R object using just R without installing minitab?

Error in read.mtp(mtwfile) :
file 'xxxxxxx//e7-10.mtw' is not in Minitab Portable Worksheet format

Comment: All my research (for the last 72 seconds) suggests that it is a binary format, proprietary, and un- or under-documented.

Comment: Install a trial version of Minitab. Save the sheet as a MTP file. Import. Also the free system: MLwin says it can read mtw files: https://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/software/mlwin/

Comment: @IRTFM I don't think MLwiN is free unless you're a UK academic - see their [pricing](https://www.bristol.ac.uk/cmm/software/mlwin/ordering/). If you can get access, it looks like you could use the [`R2MLwiN`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2MLwiN/index.html) package, specifically the `ws2foreign()` function which _converts data from one format to another within MLwiN, via MLwiN macro language_ and _supports conversion between MLwiN (*.wsz, *.ws), Minitab (*.mtw), SAS (*.xpt), SPSS
(*.sav), and Stata (*.dta) files_. Most of those formats can be read by `haven`.

Comment: @SamR : Right. I stopped reading when I got the the words "without cost". Good suggestion for alternate route, however, my reading of the docs suggests that the `ws2foreign` function relies on MLwiN to do the work.

Comment: @IRTFM yes I think it's just an R wrapper around the MLwiN CLI, and from the [source](https://github.com/cran/R2MLwiN/blob/master/R/ws2foreign.R) it also looks like it will only work on Windows.

Comment: Sevval, it sounds like you're trying to read one file. Instead of asking how to read it into R (which seems to be difficult), perhaps you can use some online resource (e.g., googling `online convert mtw`) to convert the `.mtw` file to something else usable, such as `.csv`. I did a quick search and found `https://jedok.com/converter/mtw`, though I have no experience with it (nor if it even works, nor if it is click-bait for something else ... I really don't know). Anyway, it's a different idea for getting data usable in R for you. Good luck!

Comment: @r2evans Thanks guys but this question is my homework. I think I'll just write that I couldn't find the conversion via R and add it in case additional resources are required.

Comment: @IRFTM Thanks guys but this question is my homework. I think I'll just write that I couldn't find the conversion via R and add it in case additional resources are required.

Comment: @SamR Thanks guys but this question is my homework. I think I'll just write that I couldn't find the conversion via R and add it in case additional resources are required.